# What does the comma after the target name in this assignment statement do?

Tags: python, tuples, variable-assignment, unpack

I was looking through an interesting example script I found (at [this site](http://jakevdp.github.com/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/), last example line 124), and I'm struggling to understand what the comma after `particles` achieves in this line:

```
particles, = ax.plot([], [], 'bo', ms=6)
```

The script will hit an error if the comma is omitted, but the syntax (which seems to resemble an unpacking statement) does not make much sense to me, and a statement like

```
a, = [2,3]
```

fails, which seems like an argument against the unpacking theory.

Comment: `a, = [2]` works, you just need to make sure the RHS is a single item sequence

Comment: The "unpacking theory" is not failed. See my answer below saying that `a, _ = [2, 3]` works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is needed to unpack the 1-tuple (or any other length-1 sequence).  Example:

```
>>> a,b = (1,2)
>>> print a
1
>>> print b
2
>>> c, = (3,)
>>> print c
3
>>> d = (4,)
>>> print d
(4,)
```

Notice the difference between c and d.

Note that:

```
a, = (1,2)
```

fails because you need the same number of items on the left side as the iterable on the right contains.   Python 3.x alleviates this somewhat:

```
Python 3.2.3 (v3.2.3:3d0686d90f55, Apr 10 2012, 11:09:56) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a,*rest = (1,2,3)
>>> a
1
>>> rest
[2, 3]
```

Comment: I try to unpack a tuple `p, = (1,2)` and I get the "ValueError: too many values to unpack", so your answer does not make sense. Please elaborate.

Comment: it certainly does.   `p, = `   expects to have a single value to unpack, as I now understand, but you have provided 2 values.  Thanks @mgilson.

Comment: @Serdalis -- to unpack a tuple, you need to have the same number of elements on the left as the tuple contains. (until python3 when the `a,*rest = tup` syntax was invented).

Comment: @mgilson quite true, but your answer was so ambiguous it appeared to say that you can unpack any tuple with that notation, but you have fixed it, +1 from me.

Comment: @Serdalis, otherwise, you could just use regular slicing/indexing on the tuple.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at what `plot` call returns.  In your case it's a list with one element:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> ax = plt.gca()
>>> ax.plot([], [], 'bo', ms=6)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x353d6d0>]
```

Now it would more useful in this case to have a handle on the actual Line2D object, using unpacking with `h, = ax.plot(...)`  rather than a spurious container around it as you would get with

`h = ax.plot([], [], 'bo', ms=6)`

The latter would require you an extra step later on e.g.

```
h[0].set_data(...)
```

Return value of plot is always a list, because sometimes it needs to return more than one line object.  It makes more sense to return even single lines inside a list, so that client code doesn't have to handle each case in a different way.

---

The reason your unpacking `a, = [2,3]` fails is that there are 2 things to unpack on the right side, and only one variable.  You would need to use `a,b = [2,3]` to unpack that.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of being educational, I will make this a bit long.

In Python, tuples are delimited with parentheses, e.g.: `(1, 2, 3)`.

Unfortunately, a tuple consisting of just a single element like `1` would be ambiguous (from a parsing point of view) if specified as simply `(1)`, since that could mean the *integer* one inside parentheses in the middle of an expression.

To overcome that, you can specify a tuple with just one element with the element just followed by a single comma, as in `(1,)`. (Just to make it clear, the *comma* is what makes it a tuple, not the parentheses, which we can omit when things are not ambiguous, and which is what I do below). That is unambiguously the tuple containing a sole single `1` as its element, as is illustrated in the following example:

```
>>> a = (1)
>>> a
1
>>> b = (1,)
>>> b
(1,)
>>> b[0]
1
>>> c, = b
>>> c
1
>>>
```

What you mentioned is a way to "unpack" the tuple, that is, to access a specific element of the tuple. One alternative to the syntax that you used is to index the element in the tuple by a 0, like my `b[0]` in the example above.

For tuples with more than one element, you can unpack them just by specifying an attribution with *the same number* of elements that the tuple has:

```
>>> x, y = (1, 2)
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
```

If you don't use the same number of elements when unpacking a tuple, you will get an exception being thrown:

```
>>> z, = (1, 2, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
>>>
```

In your "example" of why the unpacking theory "fails", you can simply use:

```
>>> a, _ = [2, 3]
>>> a
2
```

Note the `_` there, which is a usual variable used in Python for the meaning of "we don't care".

As an addendum, note that in `a, _ = [2,3]`, you are implicitly creating a *tuple*, which is an immutable type, from a *list*, which is a mutable type. (Note that this "implicit" conversion is conceptual, as the Python interpreter may not generate a `BUILD_TUPLE` instruction in the bytecode). Note the subtleties in the following attributions:

```
>>> a, b = [2, 3]
>>> a
2
>>> b
3
>>> a, b
(2, 3)
>>> c, d = tuple([2, 3])
>>> c
2
>>> d
3
>>> e = [2, 3]
>>> type(e)
<type 'list'>
>>> type((a, b))
<type 'tuple'>
```

Comment: Actually, it's the comma which makes the tuple.  Parens are only needed to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no tuple created implicitly here.  If you inspect the bytecode, (using `dis.dis`), the instruction is simply:  `UNPACK_SEQUENCE` and `STORE_FAST` (once for each object on the left hand side).

Comment: @mgilson, which code are you using in the case of a list? I do get `UNPACK_SEQUENCE` and `STORE_FAST` when I unpack from the tuple case (that is `a, b = [2, 3]`).

Comment: My point is that there is no `BUILD_TUPLE` bytecode in there (as there is if you do something like :  `def foo(): a = (b,c)`).  In other words, UNPACK_SEQUENCE does not create an implicit tuple.

Comment: Yes, sure, there is no explicit `BUILD_TUPLE` like in your case (which I do get in your case).