# The ,= operator

Tags: python, python-2.7, operators

While looking at some Python code I noticed usage of what looked like `,=` operator:

```
a ,= b
```

After experimentation and very close inspection of [assignment statements syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), I came to realize it's actually "tuple unpacking" with the tuple `a,` of length 1 at the left side and the collection `b` at the right. So in a simple case, it's like the following, but will also work for any iterables/generators:

```
assert len(b)
a = b[0]
```

I'm curious if this trick has a name and is there any less obscure technique that achieves the same result?

Comment: `a = b[0]` is *a less obscure technique*

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: it is incomplete without the essertion that `len(b) == 1` however.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the comma in this assignment statement do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103786/what-does-the-comma-in-this-assignment-statement-do)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such operator, it is a normal run of the mill [assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) with a target list. Most people would use different spacing, `a, = b`.

You are looking at *tuple assignment* (also called *unpacking*), and there can be more than one element on the left. Remember that it is the *comma* that makes an expression evaluate to a tuple, not the parentheses. The one-target form has no more specific name.

The left-hand side is a tuple with one element, `a,`. The right-hand side is then unpacked and must contain exactly one element which is then stored in `a`. If there are more targets on the left, the right-hand side must have a matching number of elements:

```
>>> 1,  # a tuple with one element
(1,)
>>> a, = 1,  # assigning one value to the left-hand targets.
>>> a
1
>>> a, b = 1,  # not enough elements
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
>>> a, b = 1, 2, 3  # the syntax requires an exact match, 3 is too many
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
>>> a, b = 1, 2   # two values assigned
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
```

Assigning to target lists is a normal and widely used feature of the assignment operator, even if not everyone realises this can be used with a one-element tuple as the target.

The technique is in common use when handling an API that'll *always* produce a tuple or a list, but where you expect just one value. A canonical example is a database API:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM TABLE WHERE condition LIMIT 1')
result_id, = cursor.fetchone()
```

Each row a database query result is always going to be a sequence, even if you only selected one column.

There is no 'less obscure' form of the technique, no. Once you know of it, you don't need any other technique, nor is it obscure any longer!

Comment: I think you are not answering the question asked

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I name the technique, try to address the confusion this is a special operator (implicitly showing this is normal behaviour).

Comment: The OP seems to know about tuple unpacking, they seem to want to know a *less obscure technique* to do what `a,= b` is doing which `a = b[0]` pretty much is

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: provided you make an assertion about the length as well, yes.

Comment: `a, = []` would fail the same as `a = [][0]`, I think the second is much easier to read.  I have never fully understood the logic of why a comma was chosen as the way to make a tuple.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: but `a, = [1, 2]` fails too, where `a = [1, 2][0]` does not.

Comment: Fair enough, I  still think `a, = b`  goes against Explicit is better than implicit.
 etc..  A stray comma after the that is not supposed to be there and you could get completely different output

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: you could say that for much of Python's syntax; only because you use `:` constantly do you know it is not a stray character. But what if you only learned about `{1, 2, 3}` set notation and not about dictionaries yet? It's a question of use.

Comment: I don't think it is the same at all,  I see way more errors because someone tried to create a tuple of 1 element with just parens `(1)`, the multiprocessing lib's `args =...` is a prime example, using a  comma to signify a tuple was a bad design choice in my eyes.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of unpacking. And in the code I reviewed generators were used, so b[0] simply did not apply. Now I realize that a different spacing indeed causes the left side to look like a tuple. And it definitly helps to undestand this is in common use.

Comment: @IliaBarahovski: yes, with a generator the alternative would be: `a = next(b)`, `_sentinel = object()`, `assert next(b, _sentinel) is _sentinel`. That's three lines rather than one to validate a generator produces only one element.

Answer (score 2):

The statement;

```
a, = b
```

- assumes b is iterable
- take first value from b and assigns it to a (near  to `a = b[0]`)
- asserts that b has no more values (i.e. `len(b) == 1`)

In that sense it is not the same as `a = b[0]`. The latter would work with `b = ['a', 'b']`,  while the first will raise a `ValueError: too many values to unpack`. On the other side:

```
l = [x]
it = iter(l)
a, = it    #fine when a=it[0] raises TypeError: 'listiterator' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

TL/DR: if b is a list or a tuple with one single element, both `a, = b` and `a = b[0]` behave the same, but in other cases the may behave differently