# Why does the comma symbol in Python return true?

Tags: python, operation

I am wondering why the comma symbol "," returns true:

```
mutant = toolbox.clone(ind1)
ind2, = tools.mutGaussian(mutant, mu=0.0, sigma=0.2, indpb=0.2)
print (ind2 is mutant)
>>>True
```

But when I remove the comma symbol:

```
ind2 = tools.mutGaussian(mutant, mu=0.0, sigma=0.2, indpb=0.2)
print (ind2 is mutant)
>>>False
```

it returns false. 
It would be very thankful if anyone could explain the mechanism behind this.

Comment: You are assigning an iterable containing one element to a *tuple* of names.

Comment: In other words, in your second version, `ind2[0] is mutant` will work.

Comment: Type just `ind2` to see exactly what the variable holds in each case. You'll see it's two similar, but different values.

Comment: From the [`mutGaussian()` documentation](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/tools.html#deap.tools.mutGaussian): ***Returns:** A tuple of one individual*.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, and the difference is due to the list and tuple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the comma in this assignment statement do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103786/what-does-the-comma-in-this-assignment-statement-do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`deap.tools.mutGaussian()` function](http://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/tools.html#deap.tools.mutGaussian) you are calling returns a *tuple* containing a single value:

> **Returns**:  A tuple of one individual.

When you leave off the comma, you are assigning the resulting tuple to a single variable.

*With* the comma, you are asking Python to unpack the iterable on the right-hand-side into a series of names on the left; because both the left-hand side and the right-hand-side have just one element, this work. You unpacked the value *in* the returned tuple into a single variable.

See the [*Assignment statements* reference documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

> An assignment statement evaluates the expression list (remember that this can be a single expression or a comma-separated list, the latter yielding a tuple) and assigns the single resulting object to each of the target lists, from left to right.

If you wanted to test that single value without using iterable assignment, you'll have to manually get that one value out of the tuple:

```
ind2 = tools.mutGaussian(mutant, mu=0.0, sigma=0.2, indpb=0.2)
print(ind2[0] is mutant)
```

Note the `[0]` indexing.

Answer (score -1):

When you declare or assign variables with a comma, you're creating a [tuple](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm).