# how does putting a comma after a variable is able to catch return to List[int] from typing module in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list, typing

```
from typing import List
a : List[int] = [1]
b = a
b, = a
```

How does putting a comma, give me `b = 1` else in the former case it gives me `b =[1]`. Can someone please explain this behavior, also if you find links that are useful, please add them. Thank You

Comment: `b=a` means you assign `b` to `a`. `b, =a` means output b, then.

At that time, `b` is equal to `a` which is then equal to `[1]`. You are doing iterable unpacking

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with typing. Look up "unpacking".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the comma in this assignment statement do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103786/what-does-the-comma-in-this-assignment-statement-do)

Answer (score 1):

This is called *iterable unpacking*:

```
a, b, c = [1, 2, 3] # => a = 1; b = 2; c = 3
a, b    = [1, 2]    # => a = 1; b = 2
a,      = [1]       # => a = 1
```